# Проблема с ботом для дискорда на discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Бот должен исключать пользователь из голосового канала в дискорде, после того, как пользователь напишет определенную фразу, но такого не происходит.

```
@bot.command()
async def kickm(ctx):
    member_id = 159985870458322944
    member: Member = ctx.guild.get_member(member_id)
    await member.kick(reason=f'{ctx.author} Выгнал {member}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message, ctx=None):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("..."):
        time.sleep(2)
        await message.channel.send(",,,")
        time.sleep(2)
        await kickm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь можно обойтись и одним ивентом `on_message()`

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message, ctx=None):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("...") and message.author.voice is not None:
        time.sleep(2)
        await message.channel.send(",,,")
        time.sleep(2)
        await message.author.move_to()
```

Функция `move_to()` перемещает пользователя в определённый канал, но если не указать его, то бот просто кикнет его из канала.

Comment: Спасибо, но я забыл указать, что нужно исключить конкретного пользователя с id, данным в вопросе.